# Why is it growing?

Tags: riddle

Once you have looked at it, I become more.

Once you give it to others, I become more.

Some people boost if I become more.

Some people even get money if I become more.

If I am more, everybody talks about me.

What am I?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the answer might be

> Number of views on a Youtube video (or similar)

---

Explanation:

> Once you have looked at it, I become more.

> Number of views increases by one when you look at the video

> Once you give it to others, I become more.

> Sharing the video with others leads to an increased number of views

> Some people boost if I become more.

> I think a boost in subscribers to a Youtube channel often follows in the wake of a video with a large number of views

> Some people even get money if I become more.

> Some people are able to monetize their Youtube videos

> If I am more, everybody talks about me.

> Viral videos are often a hot topic of friendly conversation

Comment: Technically, it says `everybody talks about *me*`, but I think it's probably a mistake